# Find all concatenated words in a given list of words

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, programming-challenge, depth-first-search

This is a [Leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/concatenated-words/) -

> *Given a list of words (**without duplicates**), write a program that
>   returns all concatenated words in the given list of words.*
>
> *A concatenated word is defined as a string that is comprised entirely
>   of at least two shorter words in the given array.*
>
> ***Note -***
>
> - *The number of elements of the given array will not exceed `10,000`.*
> - *The length sum of elements in the given array will not exceed `600,000`.*
> - *All the input string will only include lower case letters.*
> - *The returned order of elements does not matter.*

Here is my solution to this challenge (DFS solution) -

> ```
> def find_all_concatenated_words_in_a_dict(words):
>     """
>     :type words: List[str]
>     :rtype: List[str]
>     """
>     words = set(words)
>     output = []
>     for w in words:
>
>         if not w:
>             continue
>
>         stack = [0]
>         seen = {0}
>         word_len = len(w)
>
>         while stack:
>             i = stack.pop()
>             if i == word_len or (i > 0 and w[i:] in words):
>                 output.append(w)
>                 break
>             for x in range(word_len - i + 1):
>                 if w[i: i + x] in words and i + x not in seen and x != word_len:
>                     stack.append(i + x)
>                     seen.add(i + x)
>     return output
> ```

Here is an example output -

```
#print(find_all_concatenated_words_in_a_dict(["cat", "cats", "catsdogcats", "dog", "dogcatsdog", "hippopotamuses", "rat", "ratcatdogcat"]))

>>> ['catsdogcats', 'ratcatdogcat', 'dogcatsdog']
```

**Explanation -**

`"catsdogcats"` can be concatenated by `"cats"`, `"dog"` and `"cats"`;

`"dogcatsdog"` can be concatenated by `"dog"`, `"cats"` and `"dog"`;

`"ratcatdogcat"` can be concatenated by `"rat"`, `"cat"`, `"dog"` and `"cat"`.

Here is the time taken for this output -

```
%timeit find_all_concatenated_words_in_a_dict(["cat", "cats", "catsdogcats", "dog", "dogcatsdog", "hippopotamuses", "rat", "ratcatdogcat"])
41.1 µs ± 2.93 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

So, I would like to know whether I could make this program shorter and more efficient.

Comment: I believe there is an `O(n^2)` dynamic programming solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took me a while to understand your code since I didn't know from the beginning what each variable really meant:

- `i` is probably an int, maybe an index
- `x` is probably a number (maybe even a float), or something unknown, or a placeholder
- `seen` is a set of something, and this something could really be anything
- `stack` will only be used by calling `append` and `pop`, but what does it contain? ints, strings, complex objects? The name `stack` by itself doesn't give any clue.
- `w` could also be spelled `word`, but that one is already the best of the variable names

Therefore, to really understand what each variable stands for, I had to run your code using only pen and paper, which was a good exercise since I really don't do that often.

By doing that I noticed:

- the only purpose of the `if not w: continue` is to prevent the empty word from being output
- the only purpose of the `w[i:] in words` is to speed up the implementation; it is not necessary for the pure algorithm
- the expression `i + x` appears several times. I wondered whether the Python runtime would be able to apply common subexpression elimination to it, or whether it would make the program faster if that expression were saved into a separate variable
- I wanted to replace the `x != word_len` with the simpler `i != 0`, but I quickly noticed that this would break the whole algorithm
- using a stack is great because the larger string indices are pushed at the end, which means they are popped and checked first, which speeds up the program. At least in the `catsdogcats` case
- the `range` should not start at 0, but at 1, since for the empty word, `seen[i + x]` is always `True`
- the code is really efficient

After finishing the manual analysis, each and every little expression made sense. I didn't discover anything superfluous. Therefore: nice work. You should make the variable names a little more suggestive though.

- `i` could be `left`
- `i + x` could be `right`
- `x` could be `subword_len`
- `stack` could be `indices_to_test`
- `seen` could be `seen_indices`

One idea I had during the analysis was that the code might become easier to understand if you used a nested function:

```
def find_all_concatenated_words_in_a_dict(words: List[str]) -> List[str]:
    words = set(words)

    def is_concatenated(word: str) -> bool:
        ...
        return True

    return [word for word in words if word and is_concatenated(word)]
```

After executing your algorithm using pen and paper, I thought that another implementation might be even more efficient, and maybe lead to shorter code. My idea was:

```
def is_concatenated(word: str) -> bool:
    word_breaks = [True] + [False] * len(word)

    for start in range(len(word_breaks)):
        if word_breaks[start]:
            for sub_len in range(1, len(word_breaks) - start):
                if sub_len != len(word) and word[start:start + sub_len] in words:
                    word_breaks[start+sub_len] = True

    return word_breaks[-1]
```

This code also starts at the beginning of the long word and marks all reachable word breaks. It uses fewer variables though.

The code can be further optimized:

- for the `sub_word` length, only iterate over the lengths that actually appear in the word set
- return early as soon as `word_breaks[-1]` becomes `True`

But even with these optimizations, the time complexity stays at \$\mathcal O({\text{len}(\textit{word})}^3)\$, which is quite much when \$\text{len}(\textit{word})\$ can be up to 10_000. Space complexity is \$\mathcal O(\text{len}(\textit{word}))\$, and the initial part of the `word_breaks[:start]` list could be thrown away early.

The \$n^3\$ is because of the 2 nested `for` loops, and deeply nested in these loops is a string comparison of the subword, which also depends on \$\text{len}(\textit{word})\$.

I'd rather have an \$\mathcal O(n^2)\$ or even \$\mathcal O(n)\$ algorithm though. I just don't know whether one exists.